# Capistrano Connection Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssh, capistrano

I am trying to run `cap deploy:setup` in my rails project directory, and I am getting this error.

```
* 2013-07-06 02:46:14 executing `deploy:setup'
* executing multiple commands in parallel


-> "else" :: "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /var/www /var/www/releases /var/www/shared /var/www/shared/system /var/www/shared/log /var/www/shared/pids"
    -> "else" :: "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /var/www /var/www/releases /var/www/shared /var/www/shared/system /var/www/shared/log /var/www/shared/pids"
    -> "else" :: "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /var/www /var/www/releases /var/www/shared /var/www/shared/system /var/www/shared/log /var/www/shared/pids"
    -> "else" :: "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /var/www /var/www/releases /var/www/shared /var/www/shared/system /var/www/shared/log /var/www/shared/pids"
    -> "else" :: "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /var/www /var/www/releases /var/www/shared /var/www/shared/system /var/www/shared/log /var/www/shared/pids"
    servers: ["your web-server here", "*web-address-from-capfile*", "your app-server here", "your primary db-server here", "your slave db-server here"]
connection failed for: your primary db-server here (SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known), your web-server here (SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known), your slave db-server here (SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known), your app-server here (SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

My Capfile is this:

```
load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks



set :application, "myapp"

set :repository, "file://~/git/#{application}.git"
set :local_repository, "myserver:~/git/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

set :scm, :git


set :deploy_to, "/var/www"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true


set :user, "me"
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)

set :port, 33333


server "example.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
```

This error is really driving me crazy.  It should be noted that I'm able to ssh into my server fine with my public/private key, and sshd is set to listen on the non-default port on the remote host (hence the `set :port` line).

Answer (score 0):

So this was a silly mistake...  I was editing the `Capfile` instead of `config/deploy.rb` in my rails project directory.  The tutorial I was following at this link https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-From-The-Beginning very clearly stated to edit `config/deploy.rb`, but because I was so used to Makefiles I dove right in to the Capfile without thinking.

As you'll notice in `config/deploy.rb`, these default lines are present.

```
role :web, "your web-server here"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "your app-server here"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "your primary db-server here", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
role :db,  "your slave db-server here"
```

This is what leads to the posted issue, because of course "your web server here" isn't a connectable server.